# Why does null monkeypatch remove methods in migration but not in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, monkeypatching

This behavior is pretty cool because it makes it easy to write "futureproof"  migrations where the migration defines the model class inline in case the class is later removed from the codebase. But how does it work?

```
$ rails c
pry(main)> User.methods.count
=> 686
pry(main)> class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end
=> nil
pry(main)> User.methods.count
=> 686
```

Here's a migration:

```
class FrobulateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  puts User.methods.count

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  puts User.methods.count
  ...
end
```

And when I run it:

```
$ rake db:migrate
687
666
```

**How come the methods disappear in the migration but not in the console?**

Comment: Have you looked to see what methods are missing?  You can compare the two methods arrays.

Comment: I know for sure that instance methods that come from ActiveRecord macros like `has_many` are missing. I am guessing the the methods that are remaining are what you get when you define an empty class inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: I see what your asking.  I believe the User class created in FrobulateUsers class is really FrobulateUsers::User.  Your counting its methods when you get 666.

Comment: That's right! DOH. Want to make an answer? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing around with this, this is the true class names...

```
class FrobulateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  puts User.name

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  puts User.name

end
```

## Output

```
User
FrobulateUsers::User
```

A note, you can put this on the outside of the class...

```
# 20150810221740_frobulate_users.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class FrobulateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  puts User.name

end
```

## Output

```
User
```